# How to trigger a jquery loader using rotator.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using this plugin called Simple jQuery Circular Loading Bar with Percentage - Rotator  http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Simple-jQuery-Circular-Loading-Bar-with-Percentage-Rotator.html

This plugin is using canvas tag to draw the circle which is drawn when the jquery function is called. How can I display the circle on the html page and only trigger the percentage loading bar once I call it in the jquery.

Here is a jsFiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/fegvc5h8/

and here is the code

```
<!--html-->
<div id="rotator" style="height:100px;width:100px"></div>

//jquery
$(window).load(function () {
$("#rotator").rotator({
starting: 0,
ending: 100,
percentage: true,
color: 'green',
lineWidth: 7,
timer: 10,
radius: 40,
fontStyle: 'Calibri',
fontSize: '20pt',
fontColor: 'darkblue',
backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
callback: function () {
}
});
```

});

Comment: what you want to do with this can you please tell us in a clear way?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="rotator" style="height:100px;width:100px"></div>
<input type="button" value="Fire" id="Fire">



$('#Fire').click(function () {
       Go();
});
function Go(){
 $("#rotator").rotator({
    starting: 0,
    ending: 100,
    percentage: true,
    color: 'green',
    lineWidth: 7,
    timer: 10,
    radius: 40,
    fontStyle: 'Calibri',
    fontSize: '20pt',
    fontColor: 'darkblue',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    callback: function () {
    }
    });
}



http://jsfiddle.net/fegvc5h8/5/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fegvc5h8/16/)

```
$('#sub').on('click', function () {
    val = $('#value').val()
    $("#rotator").rotator({
        ending: val
    })
})
```